# Что это за фигурные скобки в C# и зачем они нужны?

Tags: c#

Всегда интересовало подобное, т.к. встречаю уже не раз. Что это за фигурные скобки и зачем они нужны?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Фигурные или Квадратные?

Comment: {} - фигурные; [] - квадратные

Comment: [Свойства в C#](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это [атрибуты](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/). В вашем коде с помощью атрибутов происходит сопоставление полей `JSON` структуры с полями класса, это бывает нужно для управления процессом сериализации/десериализации, например. Только это **квадратные** скобки, а не фигурные.

Comment: Может он про геттер и сеттер?

Comment: @aepot А выделены квадратные. Ну про геттер и сеттер это уж совсем как-то... хотя всё может быть

Comment: Выделены чем? Тем, что совершенно случайно курсор в этой строке оказался?))

Comment: @aepot "Случайности не случайны" ))  Можно только гадать

Comment: @CrazyElf тоесть, они нужны, чтобы более правильно парсить json объекты в объекты каких-либо классов?

Comment: @vanyavanya Ну, не только, вы по ссылке пройдите, почитайте. Атрибуты добавляют мета-информацию, которая может использоваться довольно разными способами. Но в частности да, можно прописать, что вот такие элементы json надо парсить в такие поля класса (не всегда есть возможность дать полям класса те же имена что в json), а такие-то элементы парсить вообще не надо, а тут у нас массив, а не просто поле и т.д.